# Zipcodes are missing in kibana 7.2.1 map visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, data-visualization, kibana, kibana-7

I am drawing some data on `US zip code map in kibana`, whenever I open the visualization there is an `error` popup which says:

Unable to show 43 results on map: Ensure that each of these term matches a shape on that shape's join field: `00605, 00613, 00681, 00970, 00977, 15134, 18501, 29151, 29802, 29861, 30031, 31131, 73070, 74018, 75033, 77225, 77305, 77399, 77512, 78599, 84091, 84129, 85001, 85117, 85274, 85311, 85372, 85378, 85732, 92088, 92112, 92263, 92329, 92340, 92375, 92393, 92402, 92415, 92423, 92502, 92513, 92546, 97078`

I think these are the *`zipcodes present in my data but not in kibana`*.
if this is the case, how can i add these zip codes or complete zip code boundaries to kibana?
if not, what can i do to make it work?

Also searched for some resources and found that these zip codes are not available https://maps.elastic.co/v7.2/index.html?locale=en#file/usa_zip_codes

Answer (score 0):

After searching I got to know that zip codes listed above do not represent an area instead they represent a particular Post Office Box which is a point, not area. 
I have confirmed this from here: https://www.zip-codes.com/zip-code/00605/zip-code-00605.asp